# Visual Studio C# MetroFramework MetroButton change Back Color

Tags: c#

I am looking for an possibility to Change the Button Backcolor on Button Click or on Timer.

Using MetroFramework is OK; Form Style is set to MetroForm and the Objects are usable.

I have found some code but it doesn´t work.

```
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Drawing;
using MetroFramework.Controls;
using System.Drawing;

private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //metroButton1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        metroButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
        metroButton1.Text = "button click";
        //metroButton1.BackColor.System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved

usecustombackcolor set to true

metroButton1.BackColor = Color.Lime;

thx

Answer (score 1):

According to the source code of `MetroButton` class ([on github](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui/blob/master/MetroFramework/Controls/MetroButton.cs)), there is a property:

```
    private bool useCustomBackColor= false;
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [Category(MetroDefaults.PropertyCategory.Appearance)]
    public bool UseCustomBackColor
    {
        get { return useCustomBackColor; }
        set { useCustomBackColor = value; }
    }
```

If this property is false in `OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)` there is a code which sets default background color:

```
                if (!useCustomBackColor)
                {
                    backColor = MetroPaint.BackColor.Button.Normal(Theme);
                }
```

Setting `UseCustomBackColor` should solve your problem